# Bringing USED iMacs into the UK from the USA

Tags: import-taxes, taxes

I have two iMacs, which are well used and five years old. Am I allowed to bring them into the UK for free, given their age, or do I have to pay VAT or something else at the border at Heathrow?

Comment: Are they remaining in the UK (i.e. you're returning or giving them to someone there), or are they going back to the USA with you when you return after a holiday or business trip?

Comment: Hi, they are remaining in the UK. I am giving them away. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Estimate their value (look at what they sell for on eBay, for example), and declare that at the border when you import them.  They'll be tax-free if you're within your exemption amount (which will depend on whether you're a UK resident or not, and how long you've been out of the country), or at the discretion of the Border Force officer (if [s]he feels generous, you may be allowed them tax-free even if you're over your exemption).

It wouldn't hurt to print the eBay listings you find as evidence of the value, if you're asked to justify it.

Five-year-old computers still have some value, particularly if they're Macs, so I wouldn't be surprised if you have to pay a little.

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know what the exemption amount is? Thanks

Comment: @DaveBlake Assuming you're a UK resident returning home with these goods from abroad, the information can be found here: https://www.gov.uk/duty-free-goods/arrivals-from-outside-the-eu .